# How to change the event of postcode in customer checkout address form?

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2

I am developing a custom shipping module for magento 2.2.

When you're filling out the Shipping Address form in Magento 2, periodically Magento will make an ajax request for the URL

```
http://magento.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/[hash]/estimate-shipping-methods
```

I changed the postcode text field to an autocomplete text field. Now when I type something on the text field it makes an ajax request to the above-mentioned URL. But after entering two or three characters, it shows auto suggest fields (which I added in autocomplte) and if I select one from that it doesn't generate any AJAX calls.

I added autocomplete code in my custom JS below:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("input[name='postcode']").autoSuggest(data.items, 
        {
            selectedItemProp: "name", 
            searchObjProps: "name", 
            selectionLimit: 1, 
            minChars: 3,
            selectionAdded: function(elem)
            { 
                result = elem.text();
                getresultval(result);
            }
        }
        );
    }, 6000);
```

So, my problem is when I write on the text box it works, but when I select something from the auto suggestion it doesn't work. That means the issue is with binding the event of postcode text field.

How to resolve this?

Comment: so you may be using something like onkeyup , you have to use also something like 

$("input").change(function () {
    alert("Changed!");
});

hope it will help you somewhere.  thanks

Comment: @RohitGoel This is from knockout.js.  I can't find where is this event is set?